# Positioning a custom WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, multiple-monitors

I have a custom window in WPF. In this windows I have removed the non-client areas to remove the default min,max,close buttons, default title bar and the default icon.

Now I want to:

- Enum the screens so I can select a screen to display may window.
- Query the screen about the available area to use.
- position my window on a specific screen with a specific size.

Too many questions sorry, I'm a newbie in WPF :)

Comment: Look into the [Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) type. (It is also available in the .NET client profiles.)

Comment: thanks guys. @elgonzo may you put it as answer

Comment: @m.samy: I intentionally did not put it as an answer, as i didn't provide a code example of how to use Screen and which of its properties to get the information you are looking for (blame my lack of enthusiasm and not being in reach of my Visual Studio box). I am hesitant to throw in an answer with little concrete information regarding your question. I hope you understand. However, if you like, you could post the code snippet that retrieved the information you are looking for as an answer (answering your own question ;) )